# Vue: event-bus handler is undefined

Tags: vue.js, event-bus

I want to implement event-bus in my Vue app.

First I want to make event-bus calls to start loading.
My main component's script tag where I call the `$on` look like this:

```js
<script>
    import store from '../store.js'
    import EventBus from '../event-bus';

    import Header from './includes/Header'
    import Footer from './includes/Footer'
    import Loading from './includes/Loading'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                isLoading: null
            }
        },
        components: {
            Header,
            Footer,
            Loading
        },
        mounted() {
            EventBus.$on('isLoading'), function (payLoad) {
                console.log(payload)
                this.isLoading = payload
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I got this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "isLoading": "TypeError: handler is >undefined"

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two mistakes. It should look like this:

```js
EventBus.$on('isLoading', (payLoad) => {
  console.log(payload)
  this.isLoading = payload
});
```

Mistake 1 is the closing `)` before the comma, leading to `$on` being called without a function. This is what is causing the warning message. That closing `)` should be at the end, between the `}` and the `;`.

Mistake 2 is using a normal function, leading to `this` being incorrect inside the function. An arrow function will preserve the `this` value from the surrounding scope.

I suggest using an IDE or a linter that can pick up on these kinds of problems. Your code was syntactically valid but these kinds of mistakes can easily be detected by suitable tooling.

Comment: Thank you.
I am using VSCode with Vetur extension, but it didn't threw error on it